# How can I change VBA Data Validation drop down list to disallow custom user input?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

My Excel form brings up a drop down list (red arrow in picture) when you click on one of the cells. The user can start typing to trigger an autocomplete function to better find their selection. My problem is if the user types and leaves the cell without selecting from the drop down, whatever they typed doesn't leave the cell (red circle in picture) and if they don't delete it, it becomes a problem when exporting the data.

I've already tried changing the combobox style to 2, but I got an 438 error, object doesn't support this property.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

[image: Code Screenshot 1]

[image: Code Screenshot 2]

Code:

```
Sub Auto_close()
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub

Sub Maintenance()
' This macro is a toggle and it's purpose is to prevent/allow the
' autocomplete combobox from being displayed so that Data
' Validation can be maintained if necessary.
gbMaintBeingDone = Not gbMaintBeingDone
End Sub

Public Sub ShowAutocomplete(Target As Range)
    Dim strVF As String
    Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strParts() As String
    Dim lngIndex As Long
    Dim phase_table_arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim colx As Integer, rowx As Integer, row_header As Integer
    
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    If gbMaintBeingDone Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
    'On Error Resume Next
    With cboTemp
        ' Clear and hide the combo box
        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .Visible = False
        
    End With
    
    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
        ' The cell contains a data validation list
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With cboTemp
            ' Show the combobox with the list
            .Visible = False
            .Left = Target.Left
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Width = Target.Width + 15
            .Height = Target.Height + 5
            
            ' Optionally increase the font size
            'ActiveSheet.TempCombo.Font.Size = 24
            If Not Target.Column = ws.Range("ColumnLast").Column Then
                If Left$(Target.Validation.Formula1, 1) <> "=" Then
                ' The dropdown data is a plain List of values like one,two,three
                    ActiveSheet.TempCombo.Clear
                    strParts = Split(Target.Validation.Formula1, ",")
                    For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(strParts)
                        ActiveSheet.TempCombo.AddItem strParts(lngIndex)
                    Next
                Else
                    ' The dropdown data comes from a Named Range.
                    ' Get the data validation formula.
                    strVF = Target.Validation.Formula1
                    strVF = Right(strVF, Len(strVF) - 1)
                    .ListFillRange = strVF
                End If
                .LinkedCell = Target.Address
            Else
                'Clear listfillrange just in case user selects blank row
                .ListFillRange = ""
                .LinkedCell = Target.Address
            '
            End If
        End With
        cboTemp.Activate
        ' Open the drop down list automatically
        ActiveSheet.TempCombo.DropDown
    End If
    
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

errHandler:

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ' If it's 1004 there's no data validation in the cell
    If Err.Number <> 1004 Then
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure ShowAutocomplete"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I included the code

Comment: Just a note: if there is an error, your `On Error ..` is not getting reset. You might want to include that in your **`errHanlder`** code

Comment: @Zac , should I include 'Resume Next' after the End If in my errHandler? Or could I insert 'Err.Clear()' before Exit Sub? I'm very new to VBA

Comment: Why not use a `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` or `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange` to check if the given `Target` is within your column and if it lacks of a proper second data?